# Switch statement, no case is executed

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm trying to write a function that calculates how many days have passed and, depending on the value, updates a variable and alerts that string.

I keep getting "undefined". Is my switch statement correct?

```js
var d = new Date();
var o = new Date(2015, 12, 7);
var todayDate = d.getDate();
var startDate = o.getDate();
var twelveDays = todayDate - startDate;

switch (twelveDays) {
  case "0":
    var calories = '10';
    break;
  case "1":
    var calories = '20';
    break;
  case "2":
    var calories = '30';
    break;
  case "3":
    var calories = '40';
    break;
  case "4":
    var calories = '50';
    break;
  case "5":
    var calories = '60';
    break;
  case "6":
    var calories = '70';
    break;
  case "7":
    var calories = '80';
    break;
  case "8":
    var calories = '90';
    break;
  case "9":
    var calories = '100';
    break;
  case "10":
    var calories = '110';
    break;
  case "11":
    var calories = '120';
    break;
  case "12":
    var calories = '130';
    break;
}

alert(calories);
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x28a1Lhc/)

Comment: Appears that `twelveDays` is a number (`2`) - and isn't entering the cast for `"2"` - if you case `twelveDays` as a string, it works: `var twelveDays = "" + (todayDate - startDate);`

Comment: The cases should be as @tymeJV mentioned, numeric vs. string. As a side note, is a switch required for this? **It looks like it could be simplified to var calories = (twelveDays * 10) + 10;**

Comment: You are lucky that you have to calculate only for 12 days. Imagine what that function would look like if it had to work for the whole 20th century! (hint: when the code is so repetitive, there is usually a better way)

Comment: @zvone -- Just go get an intern to copy and paste that a bunch :D

Comment: Thanks @smcd, each value will be completely random im afraid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`twelveDays` is an integer. In your switch statement, you are checking for a string. There isn't a default clause, so it throws an error `undefined`.

Change it like so:

```
switch (twelveDays) {
   case 0:
   var calories = '10';
   break;
case 1:
   var calories = '20';
   break;
case 2:
   var calories = '30';
   break;
}
```

Also, it is a good practice to add a default clause just in case

Answer (score 0):

I just updated your jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/x28a1Lhc/2/

When you use `switch`, it's a good thing to add default case.

`var twelveDays = todayDate - startDate;` returns integer.

You need cases in switch to match as integer.